# Take screenshot while not logged in (Windows Server 2000)

Tags: java, screenshot, render, jna

I've written a program in Java using JNA so I can also execute C code.

The program launches a JFrame, makes sure the window is on top and then takes a screenshot of the window (using PrintWindow of user32.dll). It saves the screenshot as a jpg and quits.

It works when I'm logged in and starts the program myself. My problem is that I want the program to run by itself on Windows Server 2000 at certain times when I'm not logged in. It appears that Windows does not bother to render the window content when that happens, the window title and borders appears but the content of the Window is black.

Does anyone know how to fool Windows into thinking that I'm logged in and has focus on the JFrame so it actually renders the content? Launching some sort of desktop emulator that in turn starts my program would be acceptable.

Footnote (offtopic): Please make it so that I can ask questions without having to make an account again. It is bothersome and makes Internet a worse place.

Comment: Well when you're not logged in, the server is running "headless" so there is nothing render. Taking screen shots of an empty desktop doesn't make much sense because even if the desktop were rendered, there would be no activity taking place to record.

Comment: But there has to be some way, I have a dll file written by someone else that can render a flash file to an image even when nobody is logged in. A window isn't even being opened visually when I run it when I'm logged in. How do you think that dll file does it?

Comment: I think it does exactly what you say it does. It takes a flash file and renders it. You can give my a flash file right now and I can render it or any other file but try sending me your desktop and let me  know ho that pans out.

Comment: How does remote desktop programs do it then? There are non-official remote desktop programs (not made by Microsoft) that send the entire desktop over Internet to a client. How does that work?

Comment: Btw, at what you said: "You can give my a flash file right now and I can render it". How? Because that is pretty much what I'm trying to accomplish here - save an image of a flash file. I have that old DLL that I mentioned that does the same thing but I want to make my own program that does it. Both in order to learn and to improve it.

Comment: RDP protocol do log in a user thats why they see the desktop. If you need to learn how to render a flash file or any other type of media than i suggest to google for a tutorial. I can render it because I wrote a game that does such things. Its a game so it won't serve a general purpose for you, its 50k lines and its closed source.

Comment: I would love to help you out and I am working on a website right now that will answer questions like those but alas I can't at this moment.

Comment: Can I somehow log in as a user via code and then launch my Java program, thus making it render? No idea how to do this. Also: Do you have any suggestion of such a tutorial for rendering a flash file? Or give a hint as to how you solved it in your game? I'm sorry for asking all of this to you but I've googled so much on this its driving me insane. Can't find any answers for years and I was close with this project of mine but then discovered that it didn't work when I wasn't logged in. Now I'm so close to a working solution since it feels like you hold all the answers which I seek! Please!

Comment: Im not tryingto hide my code from you haha. It just doesn't apply to your situation. Now do you really want to log into the remote machine or do you have a flash file already in your possion that you just want to render? I need context.

Comment: Im leaving work now and I will be home in about an hour >>> long drive.

Comment: Have it already on the local machine. Here's what I'm trying to do: A program (running as Administrator) is checking a folder for new flash files. If for example it discovers that "hello.swf" appears in the folder the program launches the screenshot-program that should open the flash file and immediately save "hello.jpg" in the same folder as soon as the flash file is showing its content. After the jpg is saved the screenshot-program quits until its next mission.

Comment: Future plans would be to take another screen after X seconds (just letting the flash file render normally like it would in a browser for X seconds and then the screenshot is taken and saved to file). Another future plan is allowing the screenshot-program to jump to a specific frame in the flash file's main time line and take the screenshot there. The DLL I have supports this but renders some stuff badly, for example ActionScript controlled graphics. Listen, I really appreciate this! Drive safely! I have to get to bed myself, it is midnight over here. I'll check back tomorrow!

Comment: Ok it look like you just want to see the content of these flash files? If you're going to look at them anyway, why take screenshots andn ot just open them yourself? What is the overall mission; the endgame, if you will. There are multiple solutions but I don't know which to give you because I still don't know what you need.

Comment: If you could post specs that would be helpful.

Comment: Morning. No I'm not looking at the flashes myself, not sure how you got that impression from what I wrote. The overall mission is that this will be an automated system for getting a screenshot of a flash file. A user can upload one or more flash files to the server, the server should then return screenshots for these flash files. See it as a thumbnail service, one that supports flash files. What I need is this: A program should open a flash file, render it, screencapture it, save it. My current problem is that nothing is rendered if I'm not logged in and are looking at the program myself.

Comment: You don't actually want to take a screen shot.  You want to either make your program write its output directly to a file, or if that's not possible, provide it an image buffer instead of a window component in which to render, and then write out the image buffer yourself.  Going through the screen and taking a capture is adding unnecessary elements into the process.

Comment: @technomage nail on the head. Don't actually render it. Get all the data you would normal collect, but directly from the file and save that as an image - problem solved.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was away during the weekend. I'd love to do what you say, but how? Are you actually suggesting I write my own flash player that read swf files and all the actionscripts etc that are inside it. If you tell me how to make the official flash player from Adobe render a flash file to a BufferedImage instead of I would love to do what you are suggesting. It sounds amazing. But how? How can I make what is supposed to be rendered on screen be written to a image instead?

Comment: I mean it's easy to say "this is what you want to do". Of course it is, but I thought it was impossible to make a program that someone else has written to render to an image instead of the screen. Please teach me how!

Comment: When you say "Get all the data you would normal collect, but directly from the file and save that as an image", are you suggesting me to write my own flash player? It would take years. There are way, way, WAY too much information in a flash movie. I thought you said that you had done what I want to do, Tyler. Are you telling me that you have actually written code that renders flash files from scratch? And it can render all the complexety that flash files can contain? Vectors, tweens, movies, actionscript controlled graphics, movieClips inside movieClips etc etc??

Comment: @Anonymous you mention at one point the flash-runner is a separate program and at another that it is a DLL.  Which is it?

Comment: I'm writing a program, it is launching a browser window that displays the flash. The browser uses the DLL by Adobe to play the flash. Then my program screenshots the browser to convert the flash to an image. If you guys would tell me how I can play the flash in my program and write it to an image directly, that would be super. I didn't think it was possible, but maybe it is? I don't really know how DLL files work.